# Meta Image not on meta question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, hot-network-questions

I just noticed that the featured question doesn't have the RPG.SE meta symbol, what's up with that?

[image]

To append to this, the HNQ are also all jacked up:

[image]

Comment: MSE bug report: [Favicon sprites are offset in site list dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381137/681403)

Comment: Ah, that explains it.

Answer (score 6):

This has been resolved, SE Dev Felippe Rangel [writes on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381143/674198)

> Sorry about that! We're releasing new site themes (have you checked out https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ lately?) and one of our themes had an issue while exporting our icons, they were exactly 1px wider than they should be for light themes.
>
> We've now pushed properly sized icons!
>
> Appreciate the fast reporting.